# how to get the index with toMap() in rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to change a List to List, and then map as Map.
The key would be "img"+index , how can I do it.

example:
from List  ["a", "b", "c"]
to Map  {"img1": "a", "img2": "b", "img3": "c"}

```
Observable.from((Bitmap[])bitmapList.toArray())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Func1<Bitmap, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    return doSomething(bitmap);
                }
            })
            .toMap(new Func1<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(String s) {
                    return "img"; // how to got the index
                }
            })
            ...;
```

Comment: Please be specific with your question. As an example you can ask the error or some thing on your posted code

Comment: I want to know the list index in the toMap() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to combine a value with an index you need some internal state: you need to keep track of a counter within the stream. You can do this with the [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#scan(R,%20rx.functions.Func2)) operator. Because you need to keep track of both that counter *and* the actual value, we first need to introduce a simple class that can hold two values:

```
private static class Tuple<T, S> {

    final T first;
    final S second;

    Tuple(T k, S v) {
        this.first = k;
        this.second = v;
    }
}
```

The `scan` operator requires two parameters: an initial value for the state and an accumulator function that takes the previous state and a new value and transforms them into a new state. The initial state is simple, it is the combination of the empty String (`""`) and an initial index (depending on which index you want to start, `0` or `1`. The accumulator is easy now: it takes the new value and increments the counter from the previous state and combines them in a new `Tuple`.

Because the initial state is not what you want to see here, you need to do a `skip(1)` to get rid of the first emitted element.

Finally you can do `toMap`, but you need to take the version with two arguments: the `keySelector` and the `valueSelector` where you get the key and value out of the `Tuple` respectively.

The final code looks as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable.from(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
            .scan(new Tuple<>("", 0), (tuple, s) -> new Tuple<>(s, tuple.second + 1))
            .skip(1)
            .toMap(tuple -> "img" + tuple.second, tuple -> tuple.first)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

*Notice that this combination of `scan` and `skip` is in fact a `zipWithIndex`, as it is called in for example RxScala. Java does not have tuples in the language so you cannot do this directly, but you have to create your own `Tuple` class for it to work.*

Comment: zipWith(Observable.range(0, length), ...) to bind Tuple maybe better then sacn()?

Comment: Absolutely, this is a perfect solution for this specific case. However, this will not work on any arbitrary `Observable` (let's say containing mouse moves) because you do not know when the `onNext` events are coming in nor how many there will be. I assumed that your source was just a dummy and that you wanted it for any arbitrary stream of which the length is not known immediately.

Comment: maybe this is a solution， but I want to found out an answer without the tuple. Thank you~

Comment: Curious about your final solution!

Comment: I'm a beginer with rxjava, so I will learn more about rxjava, maybe find a better solution. ^_^ (current solution: using zipWith with Tuple)

Comment: For avoiding create Tuple in Java you can use Pair instead.

Comment: @RvanHeest Java has Tuble its called `Pair`

Comment: Does someone have a fully written out version of this using Pair as im new to java and not sure how to do it.